# Wiring beans that do not implement an tag interface in list using Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a set of classes that extends an abstract class `Executor`. Let's say that these classes are `ExecutorOne`, `ExecutorTwo` and `ExecutorThree`. Then, I have a fourth class extending the `Executor` type, `ExecutorFour`, but also implementing the interface `NotUsable`.

I am using Spring 4.x to inject an instance of all the above beans into a list.

```
@Autowired
private final List<Executor> executors;
```

Is there any mechanism that allows me to not inject a bean of type `ExecutorFour` inside the list `executors`? I want the list `executors` to contain only three beans, respectively of type `ExecutorOne`, `ExecutorTwo` and `ExecutorThree`.

I tried to have a look at the [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation, but it seems it is no use in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in "excludes" logic. You could always write an `@Bean` method that filtered them out.

Comment: Thank you, @chrylis. That's precisely what we are doing right now :)

Comment: Perhaps constructor injection, and set the `executors` to a filtered list within the constructor.

Comment: Indeed, we are using constructor injection. I have simplified the code for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another option, it helps to achieve what you try, but doesn't answer the question directly.

Spring doesn't have an exclusion mechanism like this, after all, all 4 beans are valid spring beans and are created.

However, you can work with `Usable` interface, instead of `NotUsable` marker interface. Here is a (pretty much self-explanatory) example:

```
interface Executor {}

interface UsableExecutor extends Executor {}

class Executor1 implements UsableExecutor{...}
class Executor2 implements UsableExecutor{...}
class Executor3 implements UsableExecutor{...}
class Executor4 implements Executor {}  // note, doesn't implement UsableExecutor

@Component
class SomeClassWithUsableExecutors {

   private final List<UsableExecutor> usableExecutors;

   // an autowired constructor - only 3 elements will be in the list 
   public SomeClassWithUsableExecutors(List<UsableExecutor> usableExecutors) {
      this.usableExecutors = usableExecutors;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Spring doesn't provide a "exclude these classes" grammar for `@Autowired`, it provides  a "include these classes" support instead, in the form of 
[`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html).

The way this works is to create a custom qualifier that you'll apply at the class level to the `Executor` classes that you would want to be `@Autowired` at runtime. Spring does the rest to make sure that the undesired classes don't get into the list:

1. Create your custom qualifier, to be applied to the desired classes:

   ```
   @Target({ElementType.FIELD})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Qualifier
   public @interface Usable {
       String value();
   }
   ```
2. Apply your qualifier at the injection point:

   ```
   @Autowired
   @Usable
   private final List<Executor> executors;
   ```

What the above now does is that only `Executor` classes with the custom `@Usable` qualifier will be injected into `executors`

Comment: Can you explain more in detail your idea? I cannot understand.